# Chrome crops img background size auto 100%

Tags: css, browser, background-size

thanks to try to help me !

I would use background size auto 100% for imgs which i load from a database. Some are landscape layout, some are portrait. It's not a problem to crop it horizontally but i wouldn't vertically.

[What i have on chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccy5q.png)

[What i have on firefox and what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LUcyw.png)

Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks you and have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the background as an image?
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Do you want the whole image?
Use this code:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

Set your body background-size to 100% too.

Check this answer if it works!
Ask me if it doesn't?

Comment: Here is the link of what i'm trying to do: hugocardin.com/Test/projet.php?NOM_PROJET=SC16#article And no it didn't work, my image is sometimes croped and sometimes no.Some others are allways ok. Thank to trying help me btw